# Why do I get an access violation when I call FillChar?

Tags: delphi

Consider my sample code:

```
var p512Sector:PByte;
.....
getmem(p512Sector, 262144);
FillChar( p512Sector,262144 ,0);
```

When I run the program, Delphi gives me an violation access error. Why?

Comment: You can simply use AllocMem (http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_AllocMem.html) to get a zero-initialized buffer.

Comment: And generally, `ZeroMemory` (Windows "macro") might be more readable than `FillChar` (Delphi RTL). Notice that `ZeroMemory` *do* expect a pointer, and not a dereferenced value. (Compare `Move` (Delphi RTL) with the Windows API "macros" `CopyMemory`/`MoveMemory`. The first expects a variable, and the latter expect pointers.)

Comment: Why not use a dynamic array of byte?

Answer (score 11):

Use `FillChar(p512Sector^, 262144, 0)` (note the dereferencing ^). Otherwise you are overwriting the **pointer** and the stuff behind in memory, not the allocated buffer.

Answer (score 5):

`FillChar` expects an untyped variable. You should dereference the pointer:

```
FillChar(p512Sector^, ...);
```